# From modal window to JSON AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have a table with these fields: **product**, **lot**, **input1**, **input2**. You can clone a line, and you can add a new line.
**Product** selection is made by some value of json. **Lot** selection is empty and fill with a sub-array of the first selected item. So you choose a *Product* and you have - in the second selection - the list of the Lots of that Product. And for now, all ***works*** fine.

You can see the full code ---->> [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/d592JsS6VznPmzcEyDJm?p=preview) <<----

The problem is that I want to add an item in selected **Lots** clicking on "ADD LOT". But when I press "CONFIRM" nothing change. Why?

So, I don't know how to add a new lot, and how to add an item to the sub-array 'lots: [ ] '

In my opinion I don't have access to the product id. But I can't resolve it. Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Note: The structure of json is this:

```
[
     {
        "id":"1",
        "nome":"E0030913008 - Renal Active cane 8 lbs USA Scn",
        "codice": "E0030913008",
         "descrizione": "Renal Active cane 8 lbs USA Scn",
         "m_product_id":1019990,
        "lots":[
           {
              "id":"1",
              "value":"",
              "m_lot_id": null
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":"2",
        "nome":"test 100 33 - tett gg",
         "codice": "test 100 33",
         "descrizione": "tett gg",
         "m_product_id":1012123,
        "lots":[
           {
              "id":"1",
              "value":"",
              "m_lot_id": null
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":"3",
        "nome":"0151002 - TRIKE & BIKE 2 Scd",
         "codice": "0151002",
         "descrizione": "TRIKE & BIKE 2 Scd", 
         "m_product_id":1001716,
        "lots":[
           {
              "id":"1",
              "value":"4658",
                "m_lot_id": 1168357
           },
           {
              "id":"2",
              "value":"603",
                "m_lot_id": 1068859
           }
        ]
     }
```

Comment: Yes. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the row variable to the ng-click function that brings up the modal, and from there, pass it into the modal's controller's scope. The most relevant issue is that you're currently attempting to reference the row from the modal's scope when it had no way of getting there.